# submenus wont work action script 3 flash cc professional

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Hi and sorry in advance I'm super new and took me like 5 hours to reach this point! 
I'm working on a project to teach young and not so young how to use windows.
so far I'm almost done but I'm having trouble on making my submenus live. 
Yet so far I've completed 2 mc's on flash cc 2015 professional, its a windows start button that calls all the menu or buttons like allapps, power, settings etc..
once the menu moves can give any action to the rest of the mc's allapps, power. settings etc... get "Scene 1, Layer 'actions', Frame 1, Line 16, Column 1   1120: Access of undefined property menu1_btn."
 the current ac is the following:

```
import fl.transitions.Tween;
import fl.transitions.easing.*;
import fl.transitions.TweenEvent;

startbtn_mc.buttonMode=true;
dropdown_mc.buttonMode=true;

startbtn_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,dropUp);

function dropUp(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    var enterTween:Tween;
    enterTween = new Tween(dropdown_mc,"y",Regular.easeOut, dropdown_mc.y, 15.3, 30, false);
}

menu1_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoMovie);

function gotoMovie(e:MouseEvent):void 
{
        var moviescene:MovieClip = new movie();
        stage.addChild(moviescene);
}
enterTween.addEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH,dropUpEventListener);
}
function dropUpEventListener(e:TweenEvent):void
{
    startbtn_mc.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,dropUp);
    startbtn_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,dropdown);
}
function dropdown(e:Event):void
{
    var enterTween:Tween;
    enterTween = new Tween(dropdown_mc,"y",Regular.easeOut, dropdown_mc.y, 470, 30, false);
    enterTween.addEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH,dropdownEventListener);
}

function dropdownEventListener(e:TweenEvent):void
{
    startbtn_mc.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,dropdown);
    startbtn_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,dropUp);
}
```

I realize there are 9 buttons to go and I'm not able to move forward.
Please help!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

> Layer 'actions', Frame 1, Line 16, Column 1 1120: Access of undefined
>   property menu1_btn.

The error messages have specific meanings and refer you to exactly where and why the error is occuring:

on Frame 1 
in Layer "actions:"
on line 16 
you are referencing `menu1_btn` 
BOOM – it is undefined.

Does `menu1_btn` exist? Is it named something else? A great mystery.

None of us can tell just from the code you posted what is going on in your .fla file – e.g. how it is structured, what elements are in what frames, etc.

Half of programming is debugging. Tuck in.
(and it is completely unclear what this question has to do with "sub-menus")

Comment: inside dropdown_mc symbol menu1_btn with an instance name of menu1_btn inside the library

Comment: so this goes goes where menu2_btn? can you plese right down the complete example so i can study it and make sense of it?

Comment: I imagine that from the begininig, but I really don't know ac3 last time I use flash was it was still macromedia boxings